# I want to compute gradient descent with samples of x[100,4] and label y . when I execute the code, faced with this error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am beginner in python and when I want to execute this code faced with this error. could anyone help me?
for computing gradient descent with samples of x[100,4] and y

```
#Task 2
m,n = np.shape(x)
iteration = 100
k = 20
etha = 0.1
landa = 1
theta = np.zeros(n)
def train_classifier(theta, iteration, etha , k):
   for i in range(0, iteration):
    etha = etha / np.sqrt(iteration)
    theta = theta - etha * (1 / k) * grad(theta, x, y)
    return theta
def grad(theta, x, y):
    xTranse = x.transpose()
    cost = np.sum(logistic(x, theta) - y)
    gradiant = np.dot(cost, xTranse) 
    return gradiant

def logistic(x, theta):
    pri = np.dot(x, theta)
    hypo = 1 / (1 + np.exp(pri))
    return hypo


j = train_classifier(theta, iteration, etha , k)
print(j)
```

```
<ipython-input-3-f3d8c56159d6> in train_classifier(theta, iteration, etha, k)
     38     x1 = x[i:,]
     39     etha = etha / np.sqrt(iteration)
---> 40     theta = theta - etha * (1 / k) * grad(theta, x, y)
     41     return theta
     42 def grad(theta, x, y):

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (4,100)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems a little strange. Do you have a 100 samples with 4 different features? But only 4 labels?

Comment: I think this error is because of difference between theta and x . I removed loading data part

Answer (score 0):

this is code of loading samples and labels x,y

```
data = pd.read_csv('lab_iris_data.csv', header = None)
z = data.to_numpy()
x = z[:,0:3].astype(float)
labels = z[:,-1]
y = np.array([i == 'Iris-setosa' for i in labels])
i0 = np.where( y == True)[0]
i1 = np.where( y == False)[0]
y = y.astype(int)
x = np.c_[np.ones((x.shape[0])), x]
#plt.figure(figsize = (10,7))
#plt.grid()
#plt.xlabel('feature 1')
#plt.ylabel('feature 2')
#plt.scatter( x[i0,1], x[i0,2], x[i0,3])
#plt.scatter( x[i1,1], x[i1,2], x[i1,3])
```